# Nodejs image crop by coordinates

Tags: node.js, image, imagemagick, crop

Is there is way where we can give x, y coordinates while cropoing image.

Currently what i am using is [**Imagemagick**](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick)

```
im.crop({
    srcPath: upload_path+media_file_name,
    dstPath: upload_path+"thumb_"+media_file_name,
    width: 350,
    height: 210,
    quality: 1,
    gravity: 'Center'
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){

};
```

This code is working but i haven't got luck with `x`, `y` coordinates. The following input i want to use for image cropping

```
height:360
width:360
x:180
y:300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't speak node, but can you use the raw interface? It'll look something like

```
im.convert(['inputimage.jpg','-crop','350x200+x+y','output.jpg'],
   function(...)
```

put in your own numbers for `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Yes command is working perfectly. `convert -crop 360x360+180+300 profile.jpg testisng.jpg` same you have explained. Cheers.